# Unix command fails inside MATLAB

Tags: macos, matlab

I'm trying to automate the generation of PDF reports from data in MATLAB.
The reports are created by generating a LaTeX file and calling the LaTeX compiler from MATLAB.
This works like it should on Windows, however on MacOSX I get some strange behaviour.

First, the LaTeX compiler is called:

```
unix('/usr/texbin/latex -src -interaction=nonstopmode report.tex')
```

This works like it should, however the dvipdfm command fails:

```
unix('/usr/texbin/dvipdfm report.dvi')
[1
** WARNING ** Filtering file via command -->rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -    sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false - dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='/var/folders/jh/w14pjs0x0njfkdjlmct1rzkr0000gn/T//dvipdfmx.e9988917ae707f285b5230bc0fe87563' './TopView.eps' -c quit<-- failed.
** WARNING ** Image format conversion for "./TopView.eps" failed...
** ERROR ** pdf_ref_obj(): passed invalid object.

Output file removed.
```

This clearly fails at the first EPS image it encounters

When running in a regular Terminal, the command works as expected:

```
$ /usr/texbin/dvipdfm report.dvi
report.dvi -> report.pdf
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]
1803812 bytes written
```

Does anyone know what MATLAB peculiarity causes this error?

Comment: It could be a problem with environment variables. In general, the environment that a command sees when started from Matlab is different from the terminal environment.

Comment: Elaborating on @Deve 's post: you might try passing it to bash (or whatever login shell you use) first, to set up the correct environment.

Comment: I've set up the same environment, the latex compilation goes without problems. However the image conversion fails. dvipdfm calls rungs on the eps files, however this fails when running inside the MATLAB environment.

Comment: Fixed it by writing a shell script in the MATLAB code and calling this with the OSX Terminal program: `unix('open -a Terminal makepdf.sh -n -F -W');`